# run-time error 13 - type mismatch in if function within for loop (trying to match error against string)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to locate the first cell (row) stating "#N/A" in specific columns. I cannot work around a type mismatch error I get. I have googled and read a lot of similar stackflow questions and answers but still could not solve it.

The main things I have tried so far (besides various little changes):

- used the immediate window and debug print to check outputs (the GetDates sub is working correctly)
- converting the collection to an array where I can define a data type
- using a while function instead of for (in this case I get it to attempt the while function but on the last iteration I get a type mismatch again)

here is the full code:

```
Dim EndofWeekDates As New Collection
Dim EndofRange As New Collection

Dim lCol As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim v As Long
Dim x As Long


Sub GetDates()

    Set EndofWeekDates = Nothing
    i = 4
    j = 1
    lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    While j < lCol + 1
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, j).Value) And Not Cells(i, j).Value = "End" Then
            EndofWeekDates.Add j
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Wend

    Call GetRange

End Sub

Sub GetRange()

    Set EndofRange = Nothing
    For x = EndofWeekDates.Count To 1 Step -1
        lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, EndofWeekDates(x)).End(xlUp).Row

        For v = 15 To lRow
            If Cells(v, EndofWeekDates(x)).Value = "#N/A" Then
                EndofRange.Add v
                Exit For
            End If
        Next v

    Next x

End Sub
```

I get the error in the following section on the IF line

```
For v = 15 To lRow
   If Cells(v, EndofWeekDates(x)).Value = "#N/A" Then
      EndofRange.Add v
      Exit For
   End If
Next v
```

The *EndofWeekDates(x)* should be constant during each *15 - lRow* run while *v* changes. I have tried putting in the variable *i* (used earlier) instead of *v* and it works but only if *i* remains constant and is not changed in the *for loop*. As far as I can see the issue is with the *v* and not with *EndofWeekDates(x)*.  Furthermore, it seems that the issue only occurs when I do not use a constant but a changing number per for iteration. I tried to use the same while function as in *GetDates* but that did not solve it either.

Since *v* is declared as *Long* and I have also tried *integer*, I am stuck. Especially since the earlier used *Cells.Value* works with a *Long* which is increased in each iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line

```
If Cells(v, EndofWeekDates(x)).Value = "#N/A" Then
```

is crashing because the cell does not contain the string `"#N/A"` but instead contains an error code, which Excel displays as `#N/A`.

A comparison of the error code to a string cannot be performed as there is no type conversion that allows the two sides of the comparison to be cast to a common data type - therefore it generates a "type mismatch" error.

The correct way to test for an `#N/A` error condition would be

```
If Application.IsNA(Cells(v, EndofWeekDates(x))) Then
```

Comment: Or `If Cells(v, EndofWeekDates(x)).Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then`

Comment: @TimWilliams - checking a (valid) `Value` against a `CVErr` has the same problems as checking an error code against a `String` - there is no type conversion that allows the check to occur and you therefore get the "Type Mismatch" error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very peculiar error.  I am not sure what is causing it but using `Cells().Text` instead of `Cells().Value` will work properly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
    For v = 15 To lRow
       If Cells(v, EndofWeekDates(x)).Text = "#N/A" Then
          EndofRange.Add v
          Exit For
       End If
    Next v
```

Alternatively,

```
For v = 15 To lRow
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Cells(v, EndofWeekDates(x))) Then
      EndofRange.Add v
      Exit For
   End If
Next v
```